# Chain Size - Save Data

Tags: solidity, storage, mapping

I have the following code in my smart contract:

```
struct Member{
    string name;
    int consumed;
    int produced;
}

mapping(address => Member) public members;
```

What happens if i save 1,000,000 struct instance in the members mapping? Does that mean I will blow up the blockchain? Because on every node these data must have been saved, right?